# multiply but without using "*"

Tags: java

I have this :

```
    double multiply2(double operand1, double operand2) {
     return operand1 * operand2;
    }
```

this :

```
    double multiply3(double operand1, double operand2, double operand3) {
      // 1. Your code here
    }
```

and this :

```
    double multiply4(double operand1, double operand2, double operand3, double operand4) {
    // 2. Your code here
    }
```

i have to implement the last two methods, and i'm not allowed to use the multiplication operator.
i have to find a way to use the given method, "multiply2", instead of multiplying.

can't do it at all, someone who can help ?

Comment: Observe that `multiply(a, b, c)` equals `multiply(multiply(a, b), c)` - that should be enough!

Comment: I think this is a question to evaluate your critical thinking. How do you think you can solve this? How d you think you can use  the `multiply2` to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, it was that kind of question but in my mind for example a(b-c) = a * (b-c) and i thought i can't do that. Mental breakdown i guess, and thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
double multiply2(double operand1, double operand2) {
   return operand1 * operand2;
}


double multiply3(double operand1, double operand2, double operand3) {
  operand2 = multiply2(operand1,operand2);
  return multiply2(operand2,operand3);
}


double multiply4(double operand1, double operand2, double operand3, double operand4) {
    operand3 = multiply3(operand1,operand2,operand3);
   
    return  multiply2(operand3,operand4);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, i finally got it, i can do for example a(b-c) because the "*" itself it's not there. My bad, thank you all. Easy math, bad mind.